# python django global-ish class instance

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, global-variables

**Word of notice**: I'm just starting my first steps with django, or, whatsover, web framework design.

I'm using django rest framework, having three relevant endpoints

```
/app/ManualInput
   Receives params and generates a single random.randint(0,100)
/app/FileUploadAPI
   Receives a csv file and generates a single random.randint(0,100) per row in the csv
/app/RetrainAI
   Retrains the Artificial Intelligence blackbox (it changes it: somehow like resetting the random seed)
```

Now, i'd like to use a class instance that encapsulates the random.randint(0,100) for further refactorization, keeping in mind that two endpoints (classes) shall read from that class' instance and one endpoint (app/RetrainAI) will write to that class' instance.

I'd like to set up a robust archetype, such as, for example, avoiding session data (because, if I'm not wrong, it would hardly work with load balancers).

What is the best way to achieve my needs? Using `global` variable (class instance) in views.py?

Is this a bad design?

Thank you SO much!

Comment: Why do you think sessions will not work with load balancers? The default session storage uses the database which works just fine with a load balancer and most of the others work if configured correctly too

Comment: I might be wrong, but according to the docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/sessions/), it reads: ```It stores data on the server side``` so my thoughts are that a load balancer might redirect you a new server, emptying your session. But maybe I'm wrong.. Anyway, my custom class will not be serializable. Is this an impediment?

Comment: A global variable will definitely not behind a load balancer or in any configuration that uses multiple processes on a single machine, a global variable will only be available in the process it was created in. Is the reason you are asking for this because you have a huge data structure in a long running process?

Comment: Let's say yes: my ultimate class will take some load in ```__init__``` and quite some more on  ```.calculate()```